# Pintos gdb is not working

Tags: pintos

I am working on pintos, for my os lab, however an important tool gdb is not working.

Here is the link on their official website to use pintos http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/pintos_10.html#SEC151

However with my installation of pintos it is just not working.Here is the screenshot of what happens when i run pintos on my terminal
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2JLFvh4frRSbE11WkJRUDlSbjA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You need to run: `pintos --gdb -- run alarm-multiple`